# SELECT 0 for multiple rows of join

Tags: t-sql

I have an `invoices` and a `payments` table.

For each `invoice` record (which contains an `OriginalInvoiceValue` field), there can be multiple payments associated in the payments table.  In a `select` that joins the two tables, each `invoice` record is of course repeated for each occurrence of an associated `payment` record.

What I would like though, is to have the `OriginalInvoiceValue` field returned only once per `invoice`, and then have it return `0` (or `NULL`) for each additional occurrence of an associated `payment` record. (Such that if I were to export the data to excel and sum the `OriginalInvoiceValue` column, I actually get the real total of all invoices, instead of getting it multiplied by each additional occurrence of a payment).

Is this possible in T-SQL?

Comment: Please post the table structures, some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Best put an example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: What version of Sql Server is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sql Server 2005 or newer, you might assign row numbers to individual payments of an invoice, and left join to invoices selecting actual invoice record for first payment only. Put order by you require in `row_number()` part; I've chosen PaymentID, but payment date is probably more appropriate.

```
; with p as (
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by InvoiceID
                            order by PaymentID) rn
    from payments
)
select *
  from p
  left join invoices i
    on p.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
   and p.rn = 1
order by p.InvoiceID, rn
```

[And here is SQL FIDDLE with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaaf9/1).